# Sample Tree view in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, treeview

I want to display my data in a tree view in my mvc application.
In my tree view both parent and child nodes must act as a hyperlinks and clicking on them redirects  and performs an action result.
Also i should have facility to expand or collapse the nodes.
Can any one provide a step by step tutorial of implementation of a tree view matching my requirement?

Comment: https://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=3239285337862908617#editor/target=post;postID=8940420525636485952;onPublishedMenu=allposts;onClosedMenu=allposts;postNum=0;src=postname

Comment: I know this is super old but I had similar requirements. https://github.com/dcalugar/TreeViewExample